# Interpreting unicode data read out from a mp3 file object

Tags: python, audio, unicode, frequency-analysis

I am reading a mp3 file object using python.

```
f = open("/home/user/temp.mp3", "r")
```

My ultimate aim is to extract the amplitudes and frequencies as functions of time. I am referring to the wiki page, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure

Sample unicode:

```
edee 68c0 bb0b f65f 4ef1 62ae 8cb0 53be
3146 3c90 aa74 d558 ea62 85c1 9319 41b4
90a9 1260 e0c1 81c5 fb6c ae6b 626c 28c4
bbb2 6c4c 3d77 aee7 c5b3 a2fb 0e5d ed59
```

The wiki page, says that for every 32 bits, the 21st and 22nd bit represents the sampling rate frequency index.

a. The sampling rate freq index, (is the first and second bit in the hex to binary conversion of the sixth bit in every 8 bits). Shouldn't this be constant for a given song?

b. Is it possible to use this data, to get the frequencies at a particular instant of time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should read `.mp3` as binary file: `"rb"` mode. Why do you think your sample is Unicode e.g., are you sure you want to interpret `"edee 68c0"` as `u"\uedee\u68c0"`?

Comment: There are Python libraries that can parse `mp3` e.g., `mutagen`, `eye3D`, `pymedia`. Why do you want to parse it manually? See https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Answer (score 1):

a) Sounds like this would support [VBR encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_bitrate), where you may want to change the sample rate on the fly (is my best guess).

b) Look up [Fourier transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) - frequency has no meaning at an 'instant of time' - they need time to repeat themselves. A fourier transform will give you the frequencies present during a sufficiently long period of time. That can still be pretty short though.

Comment: Thanks. For a Fourier Transform, i.e the frequency - time mapping, I need the frequency - amplitude and time - amplitude mappings right? Is it possible to extract it from the unicode data after opening the mp3 file?